# How to do a query with every result of a query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build an application, using MongoDB and Node.JS. I have 3 models: User, Ride, Participating. 
Participating contains a userID and a rideID. It is almost as with a SQL logic: Participating links the two others models.

I'd like to, using a userID, return every Ride thanks to Participating Model

I tried to use a forEach, as the first request returns an array.

```
router.get('/getAllRide/:userID',function(req,res){
  let userID = req.params.userID
  let return = []
  Participating.find({_idUser: userID })
  .then(participating => {
    participating.forEach(element => {
      Ride.find({_id: element._id})
      .exec()
      .then(ride => {
        retour.push(ride)})
    });
    res.status(200).json(return)
  });
```

At the end of this code, the array return is empty, while it is supposed to contain every Ride whose _id is in an entity Participating.

Comment: Do you use `populate` in mongoose(https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, there are a couple of issues here:

1. `return` is a keyword. You probably shouldn't be using it as a variable name.
2. Database calls are asynchronous. `forEach` loops are synchronous. This means that you're immediately going to be returning `retour` (which looks undefined).
3. Mongoose has tools to populate nested relationships -- it's best not to do it in application code. Even if you are doing this in application code, it's likely best not to iterate over your results & do new finds -- instead, it's better to construct a single `find` query that returns all of the new documents you need.

If you did want to do this in application code, you'd want to either use `async/await` or `Promise.all`:

```js
const toReturn = [];
const findPromises = participating.map(element => {
      return Ride.find({_id: element._id})
      .exec()
      .then(result => toReturn.push(result)
});
return Promise.all(findPromises).then(() => res.status(200).json(toReturn));
```

(note: rather than using Promise.all, if you're using Bluebird you could instead use `Promise.map`.